# Why the CORS headers are required both in the preflight response and the actual Response?

Tags: security, cross-browser, browser, cors

Is there any reason why the CORS headers are required both in the preflight response (`OPTIONS`) and in the actual response as well?  I understand the reasons behind the OPTIONS request but to me it doesn't make sense to duplicate them in the actual response as well. Am I missing something?

Comment: The pre-flight response tells the browser it can make the request. Having the headers also as part of the response on the actual request alleviates the browser from keeping track of this granted permission.

Comment: But the OPTIONS request must be cached isn't it? Why is it cached if it's not used?  http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#preflight-result-cache-0

Comment: Yes, the preflight may be cached. That will only prevent the preflight from being made again. Does not change the actual request.

Comment: Isn't the OPTIONS request supposed to "authorise" the actual request? If the actual request is authorised why you would not "provide" it?  If I'm telling you that I want to eat that donut(the OPTIONS request) and you say "Yes, you may eat it", why would you take off the table when I try to eat it? Does it make sense?I mean that on the preflight you say it's Ok to make a such request and then when I make the request there is a possibility to say that it's not OK anymore.